# The following code gives the error 'Non-exhaustive pattern in function sudokuElements'...whats wrong with the code? How can i correct it?

Tags: haskell

```
sudokuElements :: [[BoardElement]] -> [Coords] -> [[BoardElement]]
sudokuElements [[]] _ = [[]]
sudokuElements _ [] = [[]]
sudokuElements ([x]:[[xs]]) (y:[ys])
    | ([x]:[[xs]]) == [inputBoardElements] && (y:[ys]) == inputBoardEmpty =
        [
            (j, i) |
            i <- (validVals [x] y),
            j <- [y]
        ] : sudokuElements [[xs]] [ys]
```

Comment: Well what about `sudokuElements [] _`? and `sudokuElements ((x:_):_)` and `sudokuElements ([x]:([xs]:_))`, etc.

Comment: I tried it but it gives the error 'Equations of sudokoElements have different number of arguments'...

Comment: Enable warnings with `-Wall` and GHC will tell you what cases you missed. I also notice that the last pattern has a guard! When that is false, the function is undefined. Worse, it is _always_ false since `[x]:[[xs]] == [inputBoardElements]` compares a list of length 2 to a list of length 1...

Comment: Yes i made the last case as undefined...but some patterns are still missing i think, which are they??

Comment: *Most* patterns are missing. Judging from your first equation, for example, you appear to think that `[[]]` is the empty list of type `[[BoardElement]]`. It is not; it is a list containing a single empty list. `[]` is the empty list of type `[[BoardElement]]`, just as it is for lists of *any* type `[a]` (no matter what `a` is).

Comment: Can you please tell which patterns are missing??

Comment: i'm writing the following as the base cases now: sudokuElements [] _ = []
sudokuElements _ [] = []
sudokuElements ([]:_) (_:_) = []  But still i get the error non-exhaustive patterns in the function sudokuElements...whats wrong with the code??

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can fix this by adding `sudokuElements _ _ = []` to the *end* of your definition, so:

```
sudokuElements ([x]:[[xs]]) (y:[ys])
    | ([x]:[[xs]]) == [inputBoardElements] && (y:[ys]) == inputBoardEmpty =
        [
            (j, i) |
            i <- (validVals [x] y),
            j <- [y]
        ] : sudokuElements [[xs]] [ys]
sudokuElements _ _ = []
```

For the missing patterns please have a look at chepners comment, he explained it quite well:

> Most patterns are missing. Judging from your first equation, for example, you appear to think that `[[]]` is the empty list of type `[[BoardElement]]`. It is not; it is a list containing a single empty list. `[]` is the empty list of type `[[BoardElement]]`, just as it is for lists of any type `[a]` (no matter what a is). 
>   Are we solving your homework assignment here ;)